# Ant tasks for JIRA

Tags: ant, jira, task

Is it possible to create JIRA issues using Ant tasks?

I'd like to automatically create JIRA issues using Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [ant-jira](http://gitorious.org/ant-jira). I never used it, looks like you can find some use and tell us how useful it is.

Comment: It seems that ant-jira is meant for that. But I had trouble with company SSO so I couldn't test it. Here's how it works :

`<target name="runtest">
  <tstamp />
  <antjira verbose="true" username="user" password="pass" webServiceEndpointUrl="http://url_to_jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2">
   <createissue verbose="true" summary="ant-jira-test ${DSTAMP} ${TSTAMP}" type="1" project="project_short_name" description="ant-jira automated test issue description" assignee="me" priority="4" />
  </antjira>
 </target>`

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ant task to execute a shell command. Make the shell command the Atlassian CLI from Bob Swift.