# Calling JIRA functions from ant

Tags: ant, jira

When we release projects I would like to do some jira checks/updates.

- Make sure the JIRA version exists for the given project
- Make sure the version doesn't have any outstanding issues
- Make sure the version isn't released already
- Release the version
- Create the next version (maybe)

Our build process uses ant and we have a standard set of tasks which every project uses.

What is the best way to interact with Jira from ant?  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531101/ant-tasks-for-jira) question but the ant-jira library mentioned doesn't seem to have support for the above operations.

Ideally, I don't want to have everyone who wants to build needing to install 3rd party tools outside of the ant deployment.  Using ant plugins is fine.

I could always write my own set of ant plugins to use the ant soap service but wondered if there was something already available that I can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JIRA has a REST API for such tasks:

http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

I did not check the details, so I do not know if all your tasks can be done with the API, but it is a point to start.

Thr problem is that there is no native task in ANT for calling and responding to REST APIs, so you would have to write a short script/program which utilizes the REST API to do your tasks within JIRA and you could call the script from ANT by the EXEC task.

Sorry, no easy solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You may try [JIRAnt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jirant). It can search Jira directly from Ant using custom tasks.